# DevTools causing browser to freeze

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have some weird thing going on in my machine. When loading a specific website at work and opening the Chrome devtools, the website's tab gets frozen, Chrome task manager shows > 100% CPU usage and all is frozen and unusable.

I’ve tried the following, none worked:

- Disabled all extensions
- Cleared cookies
- Restarted Chrome

When loading the **same URL** with devtools in **Incognito** mode, all is splendidly working and smooth as butter.

What can be the problem here? I'm using Chrome version 79.0.3945.130, which is currently the latest